# cleaning column with equivalent strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of football games that I would like to encode.
The lain problem is that sometimes team names come in different forms for the same team. For example:

```
data = {'Match': ['FC Milan - Juventus','Juventus - Milan FC ',
                  ' Juventus - Inter', 'Inter - Juventus F.C.',
                  'FC Milan - Inter   Milan', 'Inter Milan - Milan FC']}
index = range(len(data['Match']))
columns = ['Match']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,  index=index, columns=columns)
df
```

[image: df]

where 'Juventus' is actually equivalent to 'Juventus F.C.' etc. Note also some leading and trailing spaces here and there.

I want to encode the matches as a categorical variable independent from playing home or away. In the previous example the expected result shoul, thus, be:

```
[1,1,2,2,3,3]
```

---

My best attempt was to split the gales at '-' to get the team names, strip them from spaces, split them again at the eventual space and take the longest half hoping to get rid of all the useless stuff (FC, F.C., etc)

```
teams = df['Match'].str.split(' - ', expand=True) #get team names
print(teams)

test = teams[0].str.lower().str.strip().str.split(' ', expand=True) #split them
test = test.fillna('a') #get rid on nans replacing them with smtg meaningless
print(test)

new_list = [test[0][i] if len(test[0][i])>len(test[1][i]) else test[1][i] for i in range(6)] #take the longest split as team name
new_list
```

However, this breaks down for cases like 'Inter Milan' when the the halfs are equal and also shared between different teams (e.g., 'Inter Milan' and 'Milan').
Also, I am not really sure how to then encode the matches anyway...

---

Does someone see a good approach to this problem?

Comment: Have you looked into fuzzy string matching? Something like [this](https://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/)?

Comment: cooool! did not know it existed! i'll take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to make a canonical list of team names, as descriptive as possible. Then, use difflib to match each team name with its canonical name.

This could be optimized a bit, by making a set of team names from data, performing the matching over the entire set, then creating a dictionary from each unique team name to its canonical team name. I don't know what your requirements are but this probably isn't necessary.

```
import difflib # Python is batteries included

data = {'Match': ['FC Milan - Juventus','Juventus - Milan FC ',
                  ' Juventus - Inter', 'Inter - Juventus F.C.',
                  'FC Milan - Inter   Milan', 'Inter Milan - Milan FC']}

canonical_teams = (
    'Juventus', 
    'Inter Milan', 
    'Atalanta', 
    'Napoli', 
    'Cagliari', 
    'Roma', 
    'Lazio', 
    'Parma', 
    'Milan'
    #... You get the idea
    )

matches = [
    (
        difflib.get_close_matches(team1, canonical_teams,n=1, cutoff=0)[0], 
        difflib.get_close_matches(team2, canonical_teams, n=1, cutoff=0)[0]
    ) 
    for team1, team2 
    in [
        matchup.split("-") 
        for matchup 
        in data["Match"]
    ]
]

# matches =>
# [
#     ('Milan', 'Juventus'), 
#     ('Juventus', 'Milan'), 
#     ('Juventus', 'Inter Milan'), 
#     ('Inter Milan', 'Juventus'), 
#     ('Milan', 'Inter Milan'), 
#     ('Inter Milan', 'Milan')
# ]
```

Apologies for the nested list comprehension. I get lazy with routine data processing tasks.

This could be made interactive by adding logic to alert you when there isn't a very strong match so you can manually correct it. This isn't a perfect solution but my guess is it gets you 95% of the way there.